# How to increase sudo lock

Tags: command-line, sudo

Recently I came across some documentation that stated that once `sudo` was successfully ran it stays unlocked for 5 minutes and can be reset through `sudo -k`. What I was wondering was how do I increase this 5 minute timer to say 10 minutes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [`man sudoers`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/sudoers.5.html):

> `sudoers` uses time stamp files for credential caching.  Once a user has been authenticated, the time stamp is updated and the user may then use `sudo` without a password for a short period of time (15 minutes unless overridden by the `timeout` option).  By default, `sudoers` uses a `tty`-based time stamp which means that there is a separate time stamp for each of a user's login sessions.  The `tty_tickets` option can be disabled to force the use of a single time stamp for all of a user's sessions.

The "timeout" above refers to `timestamp_timeout`,
also explained in `man sudoers`:

> `timestamp_timeout`
>
> Number of minutes that can elapse before `sudo` will ask for a passwd again.  The timeout may include a fractional component if minute granularity is insufficient, for example 2.5.  The default is 15.  Set this to 0 to always prompt for a password.  If set to a value less than 0 the user's time stamp will never expire.  This can be used to allow users to create or delete their own time stamps via `sudo -v` and `sudo -k` respectively.

To modify the default setting of `timestamp_timeout`,
edit the `sudoers` configuration using the `sudo visudo` command,
and add a line near the top of the file like this:

```
# timeout after 30 minutes (instead of the default 15)
Defaults timestamp_timeout=30
```

Comment: So how do you increase the `timeout`?

Comment: Sorry again, but what should I put in the file, I saw no hints for it.